# Unknown Error during TFS 2010 build

Tags: msbuild, workflow-foundation, tfsbuild

Every so often our build process complains of the following error:

```
Cannot cancel the workflow. Agent needs to be restarted. Details: The operation could not be performed because WorkflowApplication 1bdad252-a330-4e37-9749-749ed7ceaea8 is aborted.
```

I know that this error is just a generic failure message but I can't seem to find the real error.  The things that are running when this error is sent is:  the `Run MSBuild for Project` activity and the `Associate Changesets and Work Items` activity.  (They are running in parallel).  I tried to up the logging level to diagnostic, but it didn't seem to work.

Possibly related issue, when this happens the log file for MSBuild is not created even though it does at other times.

Comment: There aren't any errors in the Event Log on the Agent?

Comment: Yes, please check the Event Log first. If you don't find anything there then you can try windbg :-)

Comment: the only errors in the Event Log are the generic `Workflow Is Aborted` error.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any custom activities in this build template or is it just the default build template? This error message, if I recall correctly, indicates that there was an unhandled exception in the process (possibly from a background thread) which caused the workflow application to be aborted. I diagnosed a similar issue a long time ago and it turned out that the unhandled exception was thrown from a customer's custom activity.

Unfortunately, I don't think the unhandled exception is reported nicely. You can try attach windbg to TfsBuildServiceHost.exe on the build machine, and set to print out all exceptions (and hope this will repro). But if you do have custom activities, take a closer look at them first.

Here's another [thread](http://blog.benday.com/archive/2010/04/20/23271.aspx) from the internet about this error that I found. Make sure you created the build share and grant write permissions to the build service account.

Comment: There are some custom build activities in the build process, however they aren't running at the time the error is thrown (at least according to the output).  And I doubt its a permissions error as its an intermittent error, and I assume it'd always happen if it was related to permissions

Comment: As you said, the error seems related to msbuild not being copied to the share. I'm wondering if there's any unhandled exception in the copy directory activity. Attaching windbg to the build service seems like the best option now...